# Ext.ux app build vs app watch (ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL)

Tags: extjs6

I have a problem I cannot solve regardless of books and google - but I assume is stupidly simple to answer for someone more skilled than me :-)

Using CMD 6.5.2 and ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL

I am trying to build a desktop application, using the sample desktop as a starting point.

I can get my desktop up and running fine, modify it, show my data - as long as I use "sencha app watch classic".

I have put "ux" in the requires list in app.json, and also using extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.App' in Application.js

So running "sencha app watch classic" shows me my desktop, but running "sencha app build classic production", and then moving the files in build/production/Desktop/ to my web server does not work at all.

I get an error like this in Chrome console: GET http://localhost/desktop/.js 404 (Not Found) (index) : 72

So the script is trying to load a js-file with an empty name, this is quite hard to explore for me, a more verbose error would have been nice :-)

Anyone have a clue as to what is going on?!

//Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your *uncompiled* version of the application in a browser (through a local web server), you may see one or more of the following warnings in the browser console:

> [W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'MyApp.view.Test'; consider adding Ext.require('MyApp.view.Test') above Ext.onReady

This means that you reference `MyApp.view.Test` somewhere, but the app does not know it is required, and thus does not load it beforehand - nor compiles it into the built version.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me on my way - even though I have never gotten such nice suggestions from sencha cmd :-)

The full answer to my problem was
1. Sencha app watch and the dev build add requirements dynamically, production does not. So that's why my app worked fine in the watch context
2. The errors I got was different depending on build, but running testing and then looking at error messages in browser dev console, not in build process (sencha app build-messages) messages helped me on my way. 
3. Finally, adding the requires "Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu" solved it. Why?! :-)

Comment: @JonasMalm ExtJS does not have dynamic requires; the developer has to add required classes as necessary, and the documentation does not tell you to. When you add `overflowHandler: 'menu'` to a toolbar, what the appropriate ExtJS factory (`Ext.Factory.boxOverflow`) does is try to instantiate the appropriate type, defined in `Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu`. That type is unavailable because ExtJS does not have it in the fixed `requires` list for Toolbar (which kinda makes sence because >90% of the applications do not use it, so it is not necessary to add it to every project).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some "requires" of extjs classes.
You can find them by running the application built with testing env, you should see in the console some usefull warnings about classes you missed to require.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but running "sencha app build classic testing" gives no errors, a few warnings coming from extjs-internals, i.e. use @import instead of requires() etc...

Comment: I have now realised that by console, you meant browser dev console, not the terminal where I run sencha cmd.