# ExtJS: Empty File Name (only .js?_dc=20181..) - 404 Error

Tags: javascript, git, jenkins, extjs, weather

For a long time I keep facing with this problem and unfortunately [sencha forums](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?469364-Empty-File-Name-(only-js-_dc-20180112155627)-404-Error) is not helping anything about. Therefore I had to bring up here.

I'm try to developing a simple weather panel. During displaying application on localhost environment it works all good but when it goes to live version it gives this error below and whole application is not working;

```
GET http://www.myapp/.js?_dc=20180112155627 404 (Not Found)
fetch @ (index):89
fetch @ (index):99
loadSync @ (index):103
load @ (index):103
loadEntries @ (index):95
processRequest @ (index):85
loadSync @ (index):85
load @ (index):85
```

As environment we are using Jenkins and `classic` toolkit during release version and this is Jenkins' commands;

```
Started by GitLab push by nengin
+ sencha app build classic
```

I've used Geolocation feature for weather panel but because of this problem I thought it keep raises error so I've take it out but still application keep give this error. On sencha forums they've suggested to me

> it happens because of a missing file/ required file. Use `sencha app build testing` to find out which file is missing. As well comment `modern` toolkit statements on `app.json` to avoid errors related with unnecessary classes.

Well.. I did all but still if I'm not disabled `weather-panel` item on Dashboard class and push it to repository, Jenkins takes commit and build the live version to internet. And keep gives this error above!

Below you will find some code snippets of `weather-panel`, what could exactly be the reason for this error? I really need some idea.

Here is whole code blocks of weather panel @ http://www.text-share.com/view/b53bd4fd

Thanks in advice.

---

**UPDATE**

Through @Alexander's comment:

So I've got this `WARN` on console: `[W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'; consider adding Ext.require('Ext.data.proxy.JsonP') above Ext.onReady bootstrap.js:867`

I've used JsonP on `weatherdata` class and it doesn't include `JsonP` inside `requires`. Now I've added JsonP and now the `WARN` is gone! So will it run without empty-file error on server with compiled application?

Comment: @Njdhv Dear Narendra hopefully you will have a chance to check this post out! =)

Comment: Please open the browser console, then work with the uncompiled app like it were the compiled app, and check for any occurrences of "Synchronously loading ..., consider adding ..." warnings. Make sure to fix all these warnings, because they cause the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ext.ux app build vs app watch (ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209684/ext-ux-app-build-vs-app-watch-extjs-6-2-0-gpl)

Comment: @Alexander that is it I guess? `[W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'; consider adding Ext.require('Ext.data.proxy.JsonP') above Ext.onReady
bootstrap.js:867`

Comment: as well here is another Info; `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: @Alexander I've UPDATED main question. Could you please check it out?

Comment: @Alexander That's it.. I've added missing requires `JsonP` through console `WARN` and now it runss!! Post your to answer if you want =) Thanks a lot man..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827295/alexander) 's comment has been the solution;

> Please open the browser console, then work with the uncompiled app like it were the compiled app, and check for any occurrences of "Synchronously loading ..., consider adding ..." warnings. Make sure to fix all these warnings, because they cause the issue.